# distinguish ido/ivy's virtual-buffers with equal names using directory?

Tags: ido, recentf, ivy

I really like the `ido-use-virtual-buffers`/`ivy-use-virtual-buffers` features, but unfortunately if you have five files named `style.css` in different projects, it is less useful. With already-opened buffers in `ivy-switch-buffer`, I see `style.css|fooproject` `style.css|barproject`, while for the stuff from recentf, I just see a single `style.css` with no distinguishing folder name. Is there a way to put distinguishers on the virtual buffers too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/issues/648, it's simply

```
    (setq ivy-virtual-abbreviate 'full)
```

It's not quite as nice as opened buffers (where only the differing part is shown), but good enough.

(I haven't found anything like that for ido though.)